# How do I get the file creation date of a source file in a NiFi flow?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am reading a file from a folder and need to rename the file on output to include a date/time value based on the file creation date. How do I get the create date/time?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information for me to help, as it's not clear what processors do you use, but you can use ListFiles to get list of files and then GetFile that will provide you the file creation time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ListFile => FetchFile` then use `file.creationTime` attribute value of `ListFile` to get file creation timestamp. Use `UpdateAttribute` to derive the required filename.

Have a look at [Apache NiFi Expression Language Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) to extract date/time part from `file.creationTime` attribute.

If you are using `GetFile` then it also has `file.creationTime` attribute.

So the basic flow would be something like - `ListFile => FetchFile => UpdateAttribute (derive desired filename)` OR `GetFile => UpdateAttribute`